# URI::InvalidURIError PostgreSQL Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, taps

Having an Issue. Running PostgreSQL,Rails 3.2.3 , Ruby 1.9.2p180 and 1.9.3(via Pik) on Windows 7 . When i try to Do

```
heroku db:push
```

on ruby 1.9.2, i get an Error

```
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Auto-detected local database: postgres://postgres:lalala@localhost/prelaunch_d
evelopment
# Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a?encoding=u
tf8
.....
Failed to connect to database:
URI::InvalidURIError -> bad URI(is not URI?): postgres://postgres:lalala@loc
alhost/prelaunch_development
# Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a?encoding=u
tf8
```

What might  i be doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with my database.yml file, 
Was using  [this](https://gist.github.com/2876868/), and it had issues. Switching to [this](https://gist.github.com/2876841) solved the Issue

Answer (score 0):

If your working on your local machine try something like this.

```
login: &login
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: yourpassword!
  pool: 5
  encoding: unicode


development:
    database: dbname
    <<: *login

test:
   database: dbname
   <<: *login

production:
  database: dbname
  <<: *login
```

Note that host:localhost was added because the default file doesn't have that.